# How can I convert a IANA/Olson timezone to POSIX.1?

Tags: python, cmake, timezone, posix, esp32

I am writing some timekeeping code for the ESP32 in C. I want to display the time in a time zone determined at build time. The ESP32 docs show how to [apply a timezone](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/release-v4.1/api-reference/system/system_time.html#get-current-time), but the format of the timezone must be in [the POSIX.1 format](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html), eg. for Sydney, Australia this is:

```
AEST-10AEDT,M10.1.0/2,M4.1.0/2
```

I'd like to be able to specify the timezone at build time as the [IANA/Olson database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) name eg. `Australia/Sydney`, and convert it to the POSIX.1 format for use in the code. The ESP32 build system uses CMake and an `sdkconfig` file, so this means either a macro defined via CMake or a line inserted into `sdkconfig` eg.

```
CONFIG_TIMEZONE=AEST-10AEDT,M10.1.0/2,M4.1.0/2
```

Is there a table or database I could look this up in, or a cross-platform utility that can do the conversion? The ESP IDF toolchain relies heavily on Python (2.7), so even something in Python could work. The less difficulty in integrating this into the build, the better. I just cannot find anything in the way of standalone utilities or cross platform libraries that are easy to wrap and call from CMake.

(I am aware that the POSIX.1 format contains less information than the IANA data, and I'd be happy simply with a POSIX.1 expression that gives the current behaviour re. UTC offset and daylight savings.)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I believe it's true that you cannot, in general, get this information from deployed `TZif` files, because as you note the IANA zones have more information in them than can be properly captured by a `POSIX` string and any such rule used to generate the file is lost in the compilation process.

Two "second-best" solutions you may try:

1. As described in [RFC 8536](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8536.html), any V2+ `TZif` file (which is to say, any file generated by `zic` since ~2004) will have a POSIX `TZ` string at the end of the data for a given zone, which is the offsets that apply in a given zone after the transitions specified in the file end. Generally, this corresponds with the database's best guess as to what the rules will be *in the future* (i.e. after 2038-01-18), but I wouldn't be surprised to find that the best guess in almost all cases is "the time zone transitions will continue to follow the current rules".

   <strike>The `TZif` format is easy to skip around in, so you'd just need to parse the header ([here is an Apache-licensed class](https://github.com/pganssle/zoneinfo/blob/fe7274f93a089316ca67aa606fc9d02e8beb0840/src/zoneinfo/_common.py#L122-L156) that you can copy-paste and convert to Python 2 if you *must*) and then skip forward to the end of the transition data to recover the POSIX string.</strike>

The TZ str is the last thing in the file, and it's delimited by newline characters, so [per Arthur David Olson's tweet](https://twitter.com/dashdashado/status/1255915267332472833?s=20) you can extract it with the following command:

```
tail -1 path/to/zone
```

2. Recent versions of the time zone database will build a `tzdata.zi` "compact text data" file which has the raw inputs to the `zic` parser. Here's [an example of the format](https://github.com/pganssle/tzdata/blob/c2ea2ba0d090e8f3b7f40f996fe73c70db07d51f/src/tzdata/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi#L2822-L2832):

```
R u 1918 1919 - Mar lastSu 2 1 D
R u 1918 1919 - O lastSu 2 0 S
R u 1942 o - F 9 2 1 W
R u 1945 o - Au 14 23u 1 P
R u 1945 o - S 30 2 0 S
R u 1967 2006 - O lastSu 2 0 S
R u 1967 1973 - Ap lastSu 2 1 D
R u 1974 o - Ja 6 2 1 D
R u 1975 o - F lastSu 2 1 D
R u 1976 1986 - Ap lastSu 2 1 D
R u 1987 2006 - Ap Su>=1 2 1 D
R u 2007 ma - Mar Su>=8 2 1 D
R u 2007 ma - N Su>=1 2 0 S
...
R NY 1920 o - Mar lastSu 2 1 D
R NY 1920 o - O lastSu 2 0 S
R NY 1921 1966 - Ap lastSu 2 1 D
R NY 1921 1954 - S lastSu 2 0 S
R NY 1955 1966 - O lastSu 2 0 S
Z America/New_York -4:56:2 - LMT 1883 N 18 12:3:58
-5 u E%sT 1920
-5 NY E%sT 1942
-5 u E%sT 1946
-5 NY E%sT 1967
-5 u E%sT
```

As you can see, for many zones this has the information you need - you need to know that the `u` rule applies to `America/New_York` starting in 1967, using the abbreviations E%sT and that starting in 2007, the rule is:

```
R u 2007 ma - Mar Su>=8 2 1 D
R u 2007 ma - N Su>=1 2 0 S
```

That is enough information to derive the currently applicable POSIX zone, though it may be more work than you're willing to do.

### Note on validation

If you go with approach #1, there is at least a useful way to validate it that the POSIX string corresponds to the current rule so that you at least get a warning that you have the wrong data, you can use [`dateutil.tz.tzstr`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzstr) to construct a time zone from the POSIX string you've extracted and [`dateutil.tz.gettz`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.gettz) to read the full data, then compare that they do the same thing in the next few years. You can refine your sampling by checking the transition points because `tz.tzstr` has an erroneously undocumented `transitions` function - it's documented on [`tzwin`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzwin.transitions), but in the current version I guess the autodoc functions didn't work correctly with `tzstr`. Then you can do something like this:

```
iana_zone = tz.gettz(IANA_KEY)
posix_zone = tz.tzstr(POSIX_STR)
current_year = datetime.now().year
for year in range(current_year, current_year + 5):
    transitions = posix_zone.transitions(year)
    if not transitions:
        continue
    dst_start, dst_end = transitions
    
    # Add your tests here
    ...
```